# sql check if all referenced Objects match condition

Tags: sql

I have a question for my SQL.
I have 2 Tables, with 1 containing the id of the other one.

So Table A is like:

```
| ID | B_ID | ... |
```

And Table B is like:

```
| ID | DATE | ... |
```

And what i want to have as an result is all IDS from Table A, where ALL B.Dates are older than 3 Years.

At this point i have no idea how i do it

Comment: Which database you are using ?  [Why should i tag my RDMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Is `ID` in table A is related to `ID` in Table B ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can structure the query using `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.id = a.id and
                        b.date > current_date - interval '3 year'
                 );
```

This uses standard SQL syntax.  Databases are notoriously idiosyncratic in their date functions.  But all support something similar, if not exactly like this.